# Monotouch crashes with NullReferenceException on non nullable object

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Here is the crash log ( short ):

> 2013-04-24 19:56:24 +0000 Memotion Unhandled managed exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
>    at Pipedream.UI.UIElement.set_Size (Vector2 value) [0x00000] in :0
>    at Pipedream.UI.StageLayer..ctor (Pipedream.ComponentID id) [0x00000] in :0
>    at Pipedream.UI.Stage.CreateLayer (Pipedream.ComponentID id) [0x00000] in :0

Actually the code of the constructor looks like this:

```
internal StageLayer(ComponentID id)
    : base(id, ComponentLayer.System)
{
    base.Size = ApplicationBase.Instance.ScreenSize;
    ApplicationBase.Instance.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
}
```

And the property looks like this:

```
public virtual Vector2 Size
{
    get
    {
        return _Size;
    }
    set
    {
        Vector2 old = _Size;
        if (SetData(SizeDeclaration, value, ref _Size, Invalidate))
        {
            CompareUpdate(WidthDeclaration, _Size.X, old.X);
            CompareUpdate(HeightDeclaration, _Size.Y, old.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Well the `Vector2` is a struct and cannot be `null`. Also this code works perfectly on desktop. I can't think of any reason why this code should crash but it also does not on iOS simulator, only on iOS-device ( I currently have no device so i'm not able to debug it directly ).

*I start some tasks before this code is called, but they using their own data and cannot conflict with the current data, even then there should not be any `NullReferenceException`.*

### Edit

It turns out that the exception is thrown when the `CompareUpdate`-method should be called. Anyway i thought that non virtual generic methods should not make any issues?

```
protected Boolean CompareUpdate<T>(DependencyProperty property, T newValue, T oldValue)
{
    if (!Object.Equals(newValue, oldValue))
    {
        ForceUpdate(property, newValue, oldValue);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Edit 2

After some more test cases i found out that that this might be a real compiler issue. The following test fails:

```
Log.Info(_Size.X.ToString()); // _Size is still a struct
```

With this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at System.Single.ToString () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Single.cs:260
>     at Pipedream.UI.UIElement.set_Size (Vector2 value) [0x00031] in C:\WORK\00_PROJECTS\16 Pipedream\00_FRAMEWORK\trunk\Pipedream\UI\UIElement.cs:332

If i change the original code to the following there is also no error:

```
Vector2 old = _Size;
if (SetData(SizeDeclaration, value, ref _Size, Invalidate))
{
    CompareUpdate(WidthDeclaration, 0f, 0f);
    CompareUpdate(HeightDeclaration, 0f, 0f);
}
```

This error also occurs when i remove the `SetData`-method, so this can't be the error cause. I've checked the this reference so the stack seems to be ok, but if i try to access the `_Size`s variable `X` and try to print it to the console the NullReferenceException occurs again.

Comment: Hard to say... the stack trace could be incomplete (e.g. something caller in the setter). In any case such issues are better solved by filing a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach a test case that shows the issue (so we can duplicate it ourselves).

Comment: @poupou Yeah maybe there is a bug in the compiler of monotouch. There is a huge engine in the back which has been written by me so i can't attach it to a bugreport. I try to replicate it later theese days.

Comment: @poupou Updated my answer, i think i've much more issues with generics which should not occur.

Comment: No doubt something is wrong but `Single.ToString()` works so there's something contextual in your project (or options) that makes this fails. We still need a bug report (for a test case and for all your project options) along with all the versions numbers of the software you're using.

Comment: @poupou I could send you this and i already created a test case ( not working, seems to be contextual ) but i won't upload the hole code to your server especially if everyone can download it. What options do we've?

Comment: You can mark the bug (or the attachement) as private. Only you and Xamarin will see (and download) private bugs/attachments. If it's too big (more than 5MB) you can give a link (private bug or comment) to download (e.g. from dropbox) and remove the test case once the bug is fixed. You can also contact support@xamarin.com to get NDA paperwork.

Comment: an other reference to a same kind of bug

http://stackoverflow.com/q/22252819/3314372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this has an architecture difference bug. The `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` line of the `Vector2` causes the Vector2 to be unaliagned which is illegal in some architectures.

Removing the line for now removed the issue.